# Advertising banner in Firefox - where does it come from and how to remove

Tags: firefox, malware, advertisements

I get an advertising banner at the top of all webpages I view in Firefox. I would like to know where this comes from and how to remove it.

[image: screenshot of issue described above]

**UPDATE**

I just realized, that when going with the mouse over the Cross it shows me "resource://firefox.abs.avira.com/html/top.html#minimized" at the bottom of the browser. I guess this means, that my AVIRA Virus Scanner, which I purchased shows advertising !!! Can someone confirm.

Troubleshooting information from `about:support`:

```
Allgemeine Informationen
------------------------

Name: Firefox
Version: 38.0.1
Build-ID: 20150513174244
Update-Kanal: release
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Fenster mit mehreren Prozessen: 0/2 (Standard: false)

Absturzberichte der letzten 3 Tage
----------------------------------

Alle Absturzberichte

Erweiterungen
-------------

Name: Avira Browserschutz
Version: 1.4.7
Aktiviert: true
ID: abs@avira.com

Name: Skype Click to Call
Version: 7.3.16540.9015
Aktiviert: false
ID: {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}

Grafik
------

Direct2D aktiviert: true
DirectWrite aktiviert: true (6.3.9600.17795)
Geräte-ID: 0x1187
GPU #2 aktiv: false
GPU-beschleunigte Fenster: 2/2 Direct3D 11 (OMTC)
Karten-Beschreibung: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760
Karten-RAM: 2048
Karten-Treiber: nvd3dumx,nvwgf2umx,nvwgf2umx nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
Subsys-ID: 360b1458
Treiber-Datum: 4-8-2015
Treiber-Version: 9.18.13.5012
Vendor-ID: 0x10de
WebGL-Renderer: Google Inc. -- ANGLE (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760 Direct3D11 vs_5_0 ps_5_0)
windowLayerManagerRemote: true
AzureCanvasBackend: direct2d 1.1
AzureContentBackend: direct2d 1.1
AzureFallbackCanvasBackend: cairo
AzureSkiaAccelerated: 0

Wichtige modifizierte Einstellungen
-----------------------------------

accessibility.typeaheadfind.flashBar: 0
browser.cache.disk.capacity: 358400
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.first_run: false
browser.cache.disk.smart_size.use_old_max: false
browser.cache.frecency_experiment: 3
browser.download.importedFromSqlite: true
browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen: true
browser.places.smartBookmarksVersion: 7
browser.search.useDBForOrder: true
browser.sessionstore.upgradeBackup.latestBuildID: 20150513174244
browser.startup.homepage_override.buildID: 20150513174244
browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone: 38.0.1
browser.tabs.warnOnClose: false
dom.mozApps.used: true
extensions.lastAppVersion: 38.0.1
font.internaluseonly.changed: true
gfx.direct3d.last_used_feature_level_idx: 0
media.gmp-eme-adobe.lastUpdate: 1431800348
media.gmp-eme-adobe.version: 9
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.lastUpdate: 1431800348
media.gmp-gmpopenh264.version: 1.4
media.gmp-manager.buildID: 20150513174244
media.gmp-manager.lastCheck: 1432187320
network.cookie.prefsMigrated: true
network.predictor.cleaned-up: true
places.database.lastMaintenance: 1432129127
places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages: 104858
plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types: application/pdf
plugin.importedState: true
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_bgcolor: false
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_bgimages: false
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_colorspace:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_command:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_downloadfonts: false
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_duplex: 1515870810
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_edge_bottom: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_edge_left: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_edge_right: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_edge_top: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_evenpages: true
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_footercenter:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_footerleft: &PT
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_footerright: &D
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_headercenter:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_headerleft: &T
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_headerright: &U
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_in_color: true
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_margin_bottom: 0.5
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_margin_left: 0.5
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_margin_right: 0.5
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_margin_top: 0.5
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_oddpages: true
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_orientation: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_page_delay: 50
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_data: 9
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_height: 11,00
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_name:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_size_type: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_size_unit: 1
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_paper_width: 8,50
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_plex_name:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_resolution: 1515870810
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_resolution_name:
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_reversed: false
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_scaling: 1,00
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_shrink_to_fit: true
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_to_file: false
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_unwriteable_margin_bottom: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_unwriteable_margin_left: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_unwriteable_margin_right: 0
print.printer_HPCF7CC0_(HP_Officejet_Pro_8600).print_unwriteable_margin_top: 0
privacy.sanitize.migrateFx3Prefs: true
privacy.sanitize.timeSpan: 4
storage.vacuum.last.index: 1
storage.vacuum.last.places.sqlite: 1431192061

Wichtige nicht veränderbare Einstellungen
-----------------------------------------

JavaScript
----------

Inkrementelle GC: true

Barrierefreiheit
----------------

Aktiviert: false
Barrierefreiheit verhindern: 0

Bibliotheken-Versionen
----------------------

NSPR
Minimal vorausgesetzte Version: 4.10.8
Verwendete Version: 4.10.8

NSS
Minimal vorausgesetzte Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC
Verwendete Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC

NSSSMIME
Minimal vorausgesetzte Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC
Verwendete Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC

NSSSSL
Minimal vorausgesetzte Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC
Verwendete Version: 3.18.1 Basic ECC

NSSUTIL
Minimal vorausgesetzte Version: 3.18.1
Verwendete Version: 3.18.1

Experimentelle Funktionen
-------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like malware. To help with troubleshooting go to, `about:support` in the Firefox address bar, click on 'Copy text to clipboard', then edit your question and paste in the copied text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helpig. I just added the text from about. Thanks

Comment: I would just delete the user profile for Firefox after I backed up my bookmarks and saved passwords or use any number of security software suites to just simply remove it.

Comment: Try a new Firefox profile (no need to delete the current one) and see if the issue persists (reboot the system as well; a system malware could be injecting them on the fly). You can use this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/) to access Firefox Profile Manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Do a 'threat scan' of your PC using [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) and remove all detected malware items. See if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I just realized, that when going with the mouse over the Cross it shows me "resource://firefox.abs.avira.com/html/top.html#minimized" at the bottom of the browser. I guess this means, that my AVIRA Virus Scanner, which I purchased shows advertising !!! Can someone confirm.